# MongoDB - Calculating the average of arrays elements across an entire collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of documents similar to these:

```
{ student_id : 13,
     courses : [
          { name : "Topology" , grade : 9 }, 
           { name : "Calculus", grade : 10}
          ]}
 },

{ student_id : 45,
     courses : [
          { name : "Geology" , grade : 7 }, 
           { name : "Architecture", grade : 8}
          ]}
 }
```

now, let's say I'd like to calculate the average of all single grades across all students (so if the above is the entire collection, we'd be looking at the average of 9,10,7 and 8)

I'm trying to do that using the `aggregate()`. I understand that I have to start with `$unwind`ing the array, but I don't understand how to move on from there.

thanks.

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/zuAYBR5TwOl

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer given by @Anthony Winzlet in the comment:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$courses"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      average: {
        $avg: "$courses.grade"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Thank you @Anthony Winzlet